# How to take batch photos in multiple resolutions through Android terminal

Tags: android, shell, terminal, android-source

I'm making some changes to the android camera library and I want to test the performance and quality of the resulting output images. In order to do this, I need to take several (e.g. 20) consecutive shots in multiple resolutions. I would like to automate this process as much as I can.

For now, I'm taking photos using the `adb shell "input keyevent KEYCODE_CAMERA"` command in a (bash) loop. At the end of each loop I have to prompt the user to change the resolution manually and press a button to continue taking pictures.

Is there a way for me to skip this user interaction completely? The only way I could think of is by recording touch events of me changing the resolution and then replaying them at the end of every picture-taking loop, but is device- (and even orientation-) specific.

Comment: Have you taken a look at frameworks/base/tests/Camera2Tests? AOSP provides some tests for the Camera that might be useful to you. They aren't typically kept up to date, but even if they don't build the information inside might be useful to figuring out your problem.